# How to make a shadow on iOS13

Tags: swift, ios13, nsshadow

I set shadow on NSMutableAttributedString,
it works on other version of iOS but not iOS 13,
the next is my code

```
let shadow = NSShadow.init()
            shadow.shadowColor = UIColor.red
            shadow.shadowBlurRadius = 20
            
            attr.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.shadow, value: shadow, range: NSRange.init(location: 0, length: (text as NSString).length))
```

It works well on UILabel attributedText，but not works well on CATextLayer string On iOS13

Comment: For shadows use the CALayer `.layer` property of the label (or other view). There are properties on it that you can set to make a shadow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iOS 14 or later

```
let shadow = NSShadow.init()
shadow.shadowColor = UIColor.red
shadow.shadowBlurRadius = 20
attr.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.shadow, value: shadow, range: NSRange.init(location: 0, length: (text as NSString).length))
subLayer.string = attr
```

ios 13 or earlier

```
let shadow = NSShadow.init()
shadow.shadowColor = UIColor.red
shadow.shadowBlurRadius = 20
attr.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.shadow, value: shadow, range: NSRange.init(location: 0, length: (text as NSString).length))

subLayer.shadowRadius = 20
subLayer.shadowColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
subLayer.shadowOpacity = 1
subLayer.string = attr
```